# Regex to sub out a formatted tag

Tags: python, regex

suppose i have `string='IT:A12-IT:B23:REMOVE-IT:C45-IT:A67:ME'`

i want the end result of the string using regex .sub to be `string='IT:A12-IT:B23-IT:C45-IT:A67'`.

I want to remove(any/any amount of) character `y` in `IT:xxx:yyy`.

I tried something like `re.sub(r':.+-','',string)`. However it removes everything. Please help thanks.

Comment: It's not clear that what you want to do, can you pls explain more about your logic?

Comment: Be sure to checkout [regex101](https://www.regex101.com/).  Helpful for trying things out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, your question is crazy confusing. But, it looks like this is the regex that you are looking for.  Change the number inside `\w{}` to delete item that has particular amount of characters. This example deletes anything with 2 characters:

```
/\bIT:\w+:(?<removeme>\w{2})\b/
```

Answer (score 0):

You want output like this:

```
>>> s = "IT:A12-IT:B23:REMOVE-IT:C45-IT:A67:ME"
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"\:[A-Z]{2,}", r"",s)
'IT:A12-IT:B23-IT:C45-IT:A67'
```